# Is there a phase diagram available for hydrogen fluoride?

Tags: gas-laws, phase, gas-phase-chemistry

Has a phase diagram for [hydrogen fluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_fluoride) been published in an article on the internet or in a book ?

Or is there a table for HF for different pressures up to 100 atm. and temperatures up to 500$⁰$ C ?

Or, even better, is there a calculator for HF, like [this one for steam](https://steamtablesonline.com/steam97web.aspx) ?

Comment: I checked Reaxys but couldn't really find anything on it. If I find some time I could check the Gmelin in our library tomorrow, they might have it.

Comment: @Justanotherchemist That would be fine, i'm mostly interested in the difference between H2O and HF from 100$⁰$ C to 500$⁰$ C. I think that could be just two parallel lines on the diagram.

Comment: Might be offtopic here but of course there is an interesting difference as HF is the only common acid that will form H-bonding bridges to itself rather than to water. Still the H-bonding donating and accepting effects are different for H2O and HF which leads to different properties. But I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: Why on Earth are you interested in HF to 100 atm. and at 500°C ? HF is such a dangerous compound.. Who would like to heat up to 500°C a sample of gaz like HF compressed to 100 atm ?

Comment: @Maurice  I can imagine you wondered ! I would like to investigate if HF could be a usefull lifting gas in the atmosphere of Venus with temperatures up to 462$⁰$ C and pressures up to 92 atm.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea anyway. Normal air is enough of a lifting gas out there.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, but for this idea i need a gas that can be liquified at about "normal" temperature and pressure so a constant height could be maintained.

Comment: I´d guess that no imaginable container material would survive this.

Comment: @Karl Maybe Teflon or Basalt fiber ?

Comment: surely not teflon. at 800 K, its as soft as ... something very soft, not to mention that it is decomposing with out without air.

Comment: So I couldn't find anything in the Gmelin either but there was an interesting page on the polymerisation of HF with a diagram. That might also something you'd have to consider at different temperatures and pressures. Sorry for the quality as I could only take a photo. 
https://imgur.com/0TkchID

Comment: @Justanotherchemist Nevertheless thanks for your effort ! I suppose the polymerisation will not be a problem for temperatures above 100$⁰$ C.

Comment: I seriously doubt that HF is the best thing for this your Venus balloon, though that doesn't mean there's no reason for a phase diagram of HF going to high pressures (maybe it could occur naturally on planets or could appear in energetic explosions or collisions), and measuring it might not be as dangerous as some would think, since these kinds of experiments are usually done with tiny quantities anyway.

Comment: @H.H.  I now agree with your seriously doubting. H$_2$O is much safer and has about the same lifting capability. But with H$_2$O the balloon would float at about 45 km, I thought maybe with just HF it could float  higher up in the atmosphere. But of course you can combine H$_2$O with He or H$_2$.

Comment: Are you trying to design balloons that would naturally stay at a height with human-survivable temperature and pressure conditions to support a human colony or mission or robot probe, and figuring it will float at the height where the lifting gas begins to condense as liquid?

Comment: @H.H.  Yes indeed, at 45 km heigtht it would be the condensing temperature of 110⁰ C and about 2 atm. so not well suited for a colony but a well designed robot probe could survive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Linde Gas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.linde-gas.com/en/images/Linde%2520Anhydrous%2520Hydrogen%2520Fluoride%2520datasheet_tcm17-446018.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjtg7exs7TnAhV8Ap0JHfPRAsEQFjAEegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2GLDPwe7mPkMDSqxeuAbIx&cshid=1580699369850) contains a vapor pressure curve.  Note that this does not extend to Venusian surface temperatures which are above the critical point.

Hydrogen fluoride may not lift as well as you think.  Its gas phase may associate through hydrogen bonding so molecules could be heavier than just HF.  See the note near the end of the safety information [here](http://www.inchem.org/documents/icsc/icsc/eics0283.htm) and note that the association could persist to higher temperature if you apply higher HF pressure than one atmosphere.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for ! Made an edit but couldn't identify the word "*peesust*"!